# Why does .readUTF() over socket fail with small files sizes?

Tags: java, sockets

I am transferring files over sockets from a client to a basic server. When I transfer small files (1kb) it fails on `String fileName = clientData.readUTF();` but with large files (31mb) it works perfectly.

It seems to me it doesn't have enough time. could anyone clarify this please?
tia

SERVER

```
public void receiveFile() 
{
    System.out.println("in receive file");
    try {
        int bytesRead;

        DataInputStream clientData = new DataInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());

        String fileName = clientData.readUTF();
        OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(("received_from_client_" + fileName));
        long size = clientData.readLong();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        while (size > 0 && (bytesRead = clientData.read(buffer, 0, (int) Math.min(buffer.length, size))) != -1) {
            output.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            size -= bytesRead;
        }

        output.close();
        clientData.close();

        System.out.println("File " + fileName + " received from Client " + clientID);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.err.println("ERROR Connection closed Client " + clientID);
    }
}
```

Trace

```
java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readUnsignedShort(DataInputStream.java:340)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readUTF(DataInputStream.java:589)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readUTF(DataInputStream.java:564)
    at example3.CLIENTConnection.receiveFile(CLIENTConnection.java:75)
    at example3.CLIENTConnection.run(CLIENTConnection.java:50)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Comment: Which line does the code fail on (print `ex`'s stack trace.)

Comment: @McDowell added to question. tia.

Comment: Well, this is all [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html#readUnsignedShort%28%29) has to say about that method throwing an `IOException`: _the stream has been closed and the contained input stream does not support reading after close, or another I/O error occurs._ I would look at the server code to see what happens when it is calling `writeUTF`.

Comment: @McDowell No, this is not all the documentation has to say. It also says 'EOFException - if this input stream reaches the end before reading all the bytes.'

Comment: @EJP - Ah, yes, I misread the stack trace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The peer has closed the connection. There is no more data. Close your end and forget about it.